# PHP Emailing Script doesn't work?

Tags: php, forms, email

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with this email script in PHP. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I had it working before, not sure what I did to cause it to stop working. It just emails the contents of the form to a specified email address.

```html
<?php 
    $action = $_REQUEST['action']; 
    if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */ 
    {
    ?>
        <div style="width:48%;float:left;background-color:#303334;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:10px;margin-right:5px;text-align:center;">
  <h2 style="color:#fde85c !important;text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;letter-spacing: 0em;display:inline;margin-right:15px;">Email Form:</h2><br />
  <form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="40" class="text-input" value="Name" style="width:375px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="mailfrom" type="text" size="40" class="text-input" value="Email" style="width:375px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="street" type="text" id="street" size="40" class="text-input" value="Street" style="width:375px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="city" type="text" id="city" size="40" class="text-input" value="City" style="width:375px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="state" type="text" id="state" size="10" class="text-input" value="State" style="width:179px;margin-right:5px;"/>
                    <input name="zip" type="text" id="zip" size="15" class="text-input"value="Zip Code" style="width:179px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="country" type="text" id="country" size="40" class="text-input" value="Country" style="width:375px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <div>
                    <input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="40" class="text-input" value="Phone Number" style="width:375px;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
   <p>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="locate" id="locate ">
                    <strong>Locate an Installer</strong>
                </label>
                <strong>
                    <label>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="become" id="become">Become an Installer
                    </label>
                </strong>
            </p><br/>
            <p>The fields above are REQUIRED<br /><br />
                <strong>
                    How did you hear about airkrete&reg; GREENsulation&trade;? <br>Please make a selection.
                    <span id="sprycheckbox1">
                        <span class="checkboxRequiredMsg"></span>
                    </span>
                </strong>
            </p>
<table style="width:250px;display:block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
  <tr>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="friend" id="Connection_0">Friend</label></div></td>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="jobspec" id="Connection_1">Job Specification</label></div><br /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="hgtv" id="Connection_2">HGTV Promotion</label></div></td>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="web" id="Connection_3">Web Browsing</label></div></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="radio" id="Connection_4">Radio</label></div></td>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="tv" id="Connection_5">TV</label></div><br /></td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div class="radiox" style="float:left;"><label><input type="radio" name="Connection" value="other" id="Connection_6">Other</label></div></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
   </p>
            <p class="clear-fix">&nbsp;</p>
   <br/>
   <p><strong>Comments:</strong></p>
            <p><textarea name="Comments" cols="43" rows="10" id="formMessage" class="text-input" value="Comments" style="width:375px;height:375px !important;"></textarea></p>
            <input type="submit" value="Send Email" name="action" class="submit"/>
        </form>
  </div>
        <div style="width:47%;float:left;background-color:#303334;margin-top:20px;margin-bottom:20px;padding:10px;">
<h2 style="color:#fde85c !important;text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;letter-spacing: 0em;display:inline;margin-right:15px;">Location:</h2><br />
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2915.660278958606!2d-76.56143805974003!3d43.04857881647236!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89d75391ea2def03%3A0x1d25241cc0ea158a!2s2710+E+Brutus+St%2C+Weedsport%2C+NY+13166!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1450154004262" frameborder="0" style="border:0;width:100%;height:300px" allowfullscreen></iframe>
2710 E. Brutus St. PO Box 380 <br />
Weedsport, NY 13166 <br /><br />

Office: 315-834-6609 <br />
Cell: 315-237-2104 <br />
Fax: 315-834-7420<br /><br />

E-Mail: info@airkrete.com<br />
Web: www.airkrete.com <br /><br />

<h2 style="color:#fde85c !important;text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;letter-spacing: 0em;display:inline;margin-right:15px;">Need an Installer?</h2><br />
airkrete&copy; Inc. has licensed installers worldwide. Many of our installers travel from City to City, State to State, and even Country to Country. Please fill out the form and we will find the best option service your request.<br /><br />

<h2 style="color:#fde85c !important;text-shadow: 2px 2px #000;letter-spacing: 0em;display:inline;margin-right:15px;">Become an Installer?</h2><br />
Installing airkrete&reg; GREENsulation&trade; is a great business with many opportunities. Once you have completed the airkrete&reg; GREENsulation&trade; training program you are an official airkrete&reg; GREENsulation&trade; Licensed Manufacturer. Please fill out the form and an airkrete&reg; representative will get back to you.
  </div>
    <?php 
    } 
    else                /* send the submitted data */ 
    {
        $locate = isset($_REQUEST['locate']) ? $_REQUEST['locate'] : "" ;
        $become = isset($_REQUEST['become']) ? $_REQUEST['become'] : "" ;
        $mailfrom = $_REQUEST['mailfrom'];
        $street = $_REQUEST['street'];
        $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
        $state = $_REQUEST['state'];
        $zip = $_REQUEST['zip'];
        $country = $_REQUEST['country'];
        $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
        $connection = $_REQUEST['Connection'];
        $comments = $_REQUEST['Comments'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name']; 

        if ((($locate == "") && ($become == "")) || ($mailfrom == "") || ($street == "") || ($city == "") || ($state == "") || ($zip == "") || ($country == "") || ($phone == "") || ($name == ""))
        { 
            echo "Not all required forms were filled out, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again."; 
        } 
        else
        {   
            if(($locate == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection != ""))
            {      
                $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to become an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.". They heard about you from: ".$connection." And left you the following comment: ".$comments;
            }
            else if(($become == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection != ""))
            {
                $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to locate an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.". They heard about you from: ".$connection." And left you the following comment: ".$comments;
            }
            else if(($locate == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection == ""))
            {
             $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to become an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.". They did not say where they heard about Airkrete from, and they left you the following comment: ".$comments;
            }
            else if(($locate == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection != ""))
            {
             $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to become an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.".  They heard about you from: ".$connection." Also they left you no comments";
            }
            else if(($become == "") && ($comments != "") && ($connection == ""))
            {
             $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to locate an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.". They did not say where they heard about Airkrete from, and they left you the following comment: ".$comments;
            }
            else if(($become == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection != ""))
            {
             $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to locate an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.".  They heard about you from: ".$connection." Also they left you no comments";
            }
            else if(($locate == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection == ""))
            {
             $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to become an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.". They did not mention where they heard about you or leave you any comments.";
            }
            else if(($become == "") && ($comments == "") && ($connection == ""))
            {
             $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to locate an installer. ".$name."'s phone number is ".$phone.". They did not mention where they heard about you or leave you any comments.";
            }
            else
            {
                $message = $name." from ".$street." ".$city." ".$state." ".$zip." ".$country." sent you an email via the contact form on the airkrete website. ".$name." would like to become an installer and would also like to locate one. ".$name." Their phone number is ".$phone.". They heard about you from: ".$connection." And left you the following comment: ".$comments;
            }
            $from = "From: $name<$mailfrom>\r\nReturn-path: $mailfrom"; 
            $subject = "Someone's interested in either finding an installer or becoming one!"; 
            mail("joseph.roberts@usa.com", $subject, $message, $from); 
            echo "Email sent!"; 
        } 
    }   
?>
```

Comment: where's your error log?

Comment: It's not giving me an error. It just doesn't send the email.

Comment: do you have access to the mail server logs?

Comment: @Dagon how would I access that?

Comment: how would i know *your* hosting arrangements?

Comment: do you have `display_errors` enabled on this script ?

Comment: TBH i dont know much about PHP at all. I can say that on submit its supposed to display the same page but instead of showing the form it should just say 'email sent'. But its not doing that.